# How is Emanuel Derman's implied tree model implied volatility skew derived?

Tags: options, option-pricing, implied-volatility, local-volatility

I am reading [Emanuel Derman's paper Patterns of Volatility Change](http://emanuelderman.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/smile-lecture9.pdf). The section, Implied Volatility In The Sticky Implied Tree Model has the linear skew approximation near the old underlying $S_0$
$$\Sigma(S,K,t)=\Sigma_0-b(K+S-2S_0)$$

A related passage is

> In the linear approximation of the local volatility model you can
> write $\Sigma=f(S+K)$ with $\Sigma$ a function of $S+K$.

I am wondering how these are derived from the implied volatility tree model which I think is the tree version of the local volatility model. Can someone please shed light on this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was also discussed in Derman's book [The Volatility Smile](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118959167) (see Chapter 16). Specifically, he approximated the local volatility by a linear function of the form
\begin{align*}
\sigma(S) = \sigma_0 -2 b(S-S_0),
\end{align*}
and then approximated the implied volatility $\Sigma(S, K)$ for an option with strike $K$ by the average of $\sigma(S)$ between S and K. That is,
\begin{align*}
\Sigma(S, K) &\approx \frac{1}{2}\big(\sigma(S) + \sigma(K) \big)\\
&=\sigma_0 -b(K+S-2S_0).
\end{align*}
This can also be treated as
\begin{align*}
\Sigma(S, K) &\approx  \frac{1}{K-S}\int_S^K\sigma(S')dS'\\
&= \sigma_0 -b(K+S-2S_0).
\end{align*}
See Formula (14.16) in the above book.

Comment: I suppose the same answers this related question https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/67909/6686?

Comment: Yes, this can answer your other question as well.

Comment: But why does $\Sigma(S, K) \approx \frac{1}{2}\big(\sigma(S) + \sigma(K) \big)$? The equation that can closest explain this is Equation (15.63) $$\frac{\ln\frac KS}{\Sigma(\frac KS)}=\int_0^{\ln\frac KS} \frac 1{\sigma(x)} dx$$ in that book. But I fail to see a reasonable path to the desired arithmetic mean. The integration is from $0$ to $ln\frac KS$ rather than, say, from $\ln S$ to $\ln K$. Would you be able to shed some light?

Comment: Please see also Chapter 14 of his book.

Comment: There seem to be several averages between the implied volatility and the local volatility: 1) mean of the squares 2) arithmetic mean 3) harmonic mean. When the variation is slow, all three are pretty close. Is that the rationale?

Comment: The rationale is informally explained in the paragraph prior to the formula.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129633/discussion-between-hans-and-gordon).

Comment: I looked up the Comment section in Chapter 14 of the book on p. 260. That seems to explain the source of the linear approximation. Is that what you are referring to ? What is the formula number you are referring to in your last comment?

Comment: Formula (14.16) in the above book

Comment: How does that reconcile with Equation (13.52) or (14.1), and the harmonic mean Euqation (15.63)? Of course, when $\sigma$ is a very slowly varying function of $S$, all three are about the same. Is this what we are assuming? Is there a better rationale?

Comment: You may need to go through the whole book to have a sense, but I am not really a fan of his rule of thumb ideas.

Comment: +1 and accepted.