# FX options: is convexity usually heavily overpriced?

Tags: options, volatility, fx, convexity

I have access to daily vol quotes for EURUSD options from 2006 to today. I was playing around with them and constructed a "daily rolled backtest" for various options constructs, like straddle, 25 delta risk reversal and 25 delta butterfly. This means I am buying, say a 1M straddle today, hold it for one trading day and my pnl would be the difference between today's and tomorrow s price. I am using the full term structure to price the options one day later, so I am considering the vol roll down. When I do this, the pnl series for straddle and risk reversal are fairly well behaved but for butterfly I get some crazy sharpes of about -5 or less for the 1M and 2M tenors. Shorting the butterfly gives me almost a straight line up in the backtest, which looks very weird. This would mean that FX convexity is heavily overpriced. If I compare this to S&P for example, things look very different. Shorting the butterflies performs rather poorly there. I am aware that this strategy I am looking at here is not tradable since the transaction costs of daily rolling are prohibitive, but can this be true? If I can find a more realistic way of rolling, I could probably still get a very profitable strategy? If convexity in EURUSD is really so heavily overpriced compared to other underlying, what is the reason?

Comment: How exactly did you do this with what data? If you use daily rolls, you will need to either manually compute the 1m-1d vol via interpolation, or you use some vendor computed value. Butterflies are the main building block (with ATM DNS and RR) for [FX vol surface costruction](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/63649/54838). Insofar, if you could easily get a (very) profitable strategy, I would say it would imply that all market makers are consistently giving away free lunches.

Comment: If I only look at 1M tenor, I need data for the volsurface of 1M and the next tenor shorter than that, I.e. 3W. Then I can interpolate the "1M minus 1 trading day" vol surface which is used to price yesterday's 1M options on today's market.

Comment: There was a sellside piece earlier in the year on trading FX vol. In it, they looked at trading long strangles vs straddles but gamma-weighted (so not really a 'true' fly). Their conclusion was, "This strategy performs well before transaction costs, confirming the existence of a structural vol of vol premium. Unfortunately it does not survive transaction costs". I.e. flies should be fairly priced, not a free lunch/Sharpe of 5.

Comment: Thanks. I would be very interested in this piece. I suppose you cannot send it to me, but do you know the name of the bank and maybe the title, so I can check if my institution is subscribed to this?

Comment: Hi Ben - SocGen piece titled "Systematic trading in options: Looking for premium in currencies across the globe", Feb 2020. I was mistaken in writing that it was published earlier this year.